# Can I use filled.contour to plot data with decimal cartesian coordinates?

Tags: r, plot

I have a 288000x3 matrix (288000 rows, 3 columns) of x and y cartesian coordinates from -60 to 60 with decimals that trail to 8 places along with a value at those coordinates.

Example-

```
        y.cart     x.cart      value
[1,] 0.001308930 0.07498858  -49.36752
[2,] 0.002617462 0.07495431  -48.33903
[3,] 0.003925197 0.07489722  -51.42450
[4,] 0.005231736 0.07481730  -51.93874
[5,] 0.006536681 0.07471460 -513.73075
[6,] 0.007839635 0.07458914  -52.45299
[7,] 0.009140201 0.07444096  -51.93874
[8,] 0.010437983 0.07427011  -48.85327
[9,] 0.011732585 0.07407663  -49.36752
[10,] 0.013023613 0.07386058  -50.91025
```

This is weather radar reflectivity data and I need to plot it to look like the output that filled.contour creates, but in order to use filled.contour, the values need to be in a matrix because the function uses the matrix position as the coordinates for the plot which doesn't work with the way that my data is organized. Is there a way to use a filled.contour with the data in this form or, is there another way to do this? I've been fiddling with it for two days and haven't gotten very far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the value column in a Matrix. This can done in a for loop. But for this I make the assumption, that in your data the y and x values in the variables y.cart and x.cart are not unique. I did this because I think you have something like a map and on this map every point from a grid is a pair of coordinates.

Is this correct you can try this code:

```
# Some sample data:
y.cart <- x.cart <- seq(-60,60,length.out = 600)

# Bring it in the form like your data are:
DF <- data.frame(x.cart = sample(x = x.cart, length(x.cart)^2, replace = TRUE), 
                 y.cart = sample(x = y.cart, length(y.cart)^2, replace = TRUE), 
                 value = rnorm(length(y.cart)^2))

# Also works for a Matrix:
DF <- as.matrix(DF)

# Define the Matrix Z. In this Matrix are just NAs, because if a value on a 
# special coordinate doesn't exist there should be nothing drawn:
Z <- matrix(rep(NA,length(DF[,1])^2), nrow = length(DF[,1]))

# Get the unique points which represent the x and y coordinate. It's important
# to use the unique points for getting the index for the Matrix out of this vectors: 
x <- sort(unique(DF[,1]))
y <- sort(unique(DF[,2]))

# In this loop every row in de data.frame (or matrix) is matched with the vector
# x for the i-th row in the Matrix and with the vector y for the j-th column in
# the Matrix Z[i,j]:
for(i in seq(along = DF[,1])) {

  Z[which(x == DF[i,1]),which(y == DF[i,2])] <- DF[i,3]

}

# Now you can use persp or filled.contour with the following call:
persp(x,y,Z)
filled.contour(x,y,Z)
```

This works for my sample data, even though it makes no sense for them. Keep in your mind that the for loop isn't very fast and with your data it could take a while. You can build in a process bar to controle the status from the loop with:

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 1, max = length(DF[,1]), style = 3)
for(i in seq(along = DF[,1])) {

  Z[which(x == DF[i,1]),which(y == DF[i,2])] <- DF[i,3]

  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
```

Also it's necessary that x and y have the same length and the Matrix Z is a Matrix with dimensions lenght(x) and length(y).

I hope this works for you. If my thinkings about the data aren't true you can maybe give a little more details about the data. And do not forget to replace DF with the name of your matrix.